# How to use existing data with azure?

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-dotnet-backend-use-existing-sql-database/

I have been following this tutorial but it ends up creating a new table emptying all the data. How do I make it uses existing values inside an existing table?

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial indeed populate example data using `Database.SetInitializer(new ExistingInitializer());` but it wont make new DB.
Make sure you have correct connection string `Name=MS_TableConnectionString` (step 4 in Exploring the existing database model) so it points out to you existing DB

**Edit:**

First of all, comment out database seeder `Database.SetInitializer(new ExistingInitializer());` and to query your existing data use `GetAllMobileCustomers` in `MobileCustomerController` or `GetAllMobileOrders` in `MobileOrderController` it will give you `IQueryable` of `MobileCustomer` of `MobileOrder` object, use that object as you wish

Comment: That was a mistake. What I meant to say is it creates a new empty table.

Comment: don't forget to accept this as answer if it works so it will also help people that have the same problem

Comment: If I were to reinsert existing data from a table onto itself so that the four fields in the tutorial can be auto generated, where and how would I do it?

Comment: what fields do you mean?

Comment: CreatedAt,Deleted,Id,Updatedat,version